# Does Apple allow changing from Non-consumable IAP to Subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS App with a Non-consumable In-App Purchase, now I want to change my app to subscription business model. Does Apple Review Guidelines allow this change?

Surely the old purchaser can continue to use the app without paying again.

Comment: @matt, My question is does Apple allow this, not how. Please reopen my question. Thanks.

Comment: And the answer, as you'll see if you click the link, is No. Your question adds nothing to the existing question-and-answer, so marking as a duplicate is correct.

Comment: @matt, I did check the answer, the answer is a programmatic answer. But I am asking does Apple allow this change in their app review. Does this violate the review guideline?  Not Yes or No in the coding level.

Comment: Questions about what Apple will allow in app review are not on topic for Stack Overflow. We are programmers, not lawyers or mind-readers. You are certainly free to try what you want and see if it gets past the review. Your question was "Surely the old purchaser can continue to use the app without paying again", and the duplicate responds to exactly that. You are not penalized in any way by having the question marked as a duplicate. The link _helps_ you. And of course you're quite free to try to get the question re-opened.

Comment: @matt, you don't have to be a lawyers or mind-readers to answer my question. I just hope someone experienced this before can answer my question. This can help me a lot. Apple won't answer my question. Stackoverflow is a place for developer, I think this question could get answered here and can help other developers in the future as well. But you stopped this. I don't see the old question and answer is helping me.